# Custom tag-colors for imported tag library tags in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tags, settings

Is it somehow possible to change the tag-colors (not one-by-one, but for all of them... or else one-by-one would also be okay) of imported tag library tags (like e.g. `jstl`-tags: `<c:if>`, `<c:forEach>`, or `<my:tag>`, etc.)? Just to make some visual difference within a JSP-code between usual HTML-tags and all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Other than Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring, I'm pretty sure you can't change tag colors for custom tags.